# NowJS manually initiating a new connection after a lost connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

i have a case where clients connect to a node.js server running nowjs and remain connected for a fairly long time (about 30 minutes). on some browsers though the connection gets dropped after a while and the client disconnects.

i implemented a disconnect handler on the client side like this:

```
now.core.on('disconnect', function () {
    // we should reconnect here, maybe after a short timeout
});
```

what i am unclear about is how exactly to trigger a reconnect. this might be something blatantly obvious to experienced users but i didn't manage to figure this out.

the now.js script initializes on page load and after that i can use the now object, but i can't figure out how to repeat this process without reloading the page.

thanks!

Comment: The socket.io guys (v0.7 which is a week old) are playing around with automatic reconnects. Go ask #socket.io and #nowjs what the future plans are for automatic reconnects. (That's IRC on freenode btw)

Comment: thanks for the hint! i think it is already doing it's thing since i just set up a new server with nowjs on it, installed the exact same app and it loses the connection but seems to get it back up on its own?!?

Comment: socket.io already has a reconnect option, why not use it?

Comment: ok, one difference, i tried a call to now.core.reconnect(); i got drop outs, the client reconnected. but i also got one "reconnect" is not a function error... so is it a function of now.core or isn't it? maybe anyone here knows for sure.

Comment: Their site says "In the current version of NowJS, automatic reconnects are not fully supported." Too bad.

Comment: @davin: you are right, but i have no deep knowledge of either one, now.js and socket.io that is. so since now.js is sitting on top of socket.io i have no clue where to use what. so maybe now.core.reconnect(); is the socket.io reconnect function?

Comment: If you're using now.js and they don't support reconnect, then you're in a bit of trouble. Even if you get the underlying socket to perform its native reconnect logic, you might mess up now.js's invariants. Either work with the now.js team to add that support, or forget reconnecting, or ditch now.js. Not sure if there are any other options.

Comment: I should add that I'm not all that familiar with now.js, so you should probably ask one of their team as Raynos suggested.

Comment: Socket.io has had a large revamp over the recent weeks. The nowjs team are incomperating that into the build. I know the socket.io guys are ironing out bugs into the automatic reconnect and like you said you should go talk to the nowjs on the ETA for the new socket.io features being in the nowjs build. However you can do plenty of monkey patching to do this, the support just won't be out of the box.

Comment: @davin @DasAntonym [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) is the other abstraction on socket.io that's worth using. Go ask SubStack on #nowjs about differences for automatic reconnect support in dnode / nowjs / socket.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, automatic reconnects are supported with NowJS, as of v0.6.1.

The website needs to be updated, but there's a blog post detailed the implementation of reconnects in NowJS [here](http://blog.nowjs.com/nowjs-and-reconnecting).

Comment: I will make sure we do that Raynos! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the site is a bit outdated -- as of version 0.6.1 (released on June 10; current version on npm), automatic reconnects are supported. It mostly just takes advantage of the automatic reconnect feature in Socket.IO v0.6.18, although there were a few other miscellaneous tweaks that had to be made (there's apparently a blog post about it at [blog.nowjs.com](http://blog.nowjs.com)).